# Angularjs $interval.flush()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, web

I have an $interval running to ping a server, but sometimes I want to skip to the next update immediately so I tried flush() with the refresh rate. To force the next call. This would have the added benifit of making sure that two requests were not in transit at the same time.

```
   $interval.flush(refrsh_rate);
```

When this runs it get this error

```
  TypeError: $interval.flush is not a function
```

There isn't a ton of documentation on interval, but it seems to be mostly referenced from ngMock. That is for unit testing though. What am I doing wrong? or is there a better way achieving this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the $interval documentation -- [AngularJS $interval Service API Reference -- Cancel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#cancel). It includes an example on how to stop and restart a `$interval` operation.

Comment: Yes you can cancel it but I want the interval to keep running. Is there a better way to do this then canceling the promis running the function and restarting it? I think that solution would introduce race conditions any way.

Comment: I would trust the individual promises from `$timeout` to cancel properly. Since `$interval` doesn't chain promises, I wouldn't trust it for firing off XHRs.

Comment: $timeout doesn't really work for my purposes since I want to keep pinging at a certain interval not just once after a time period. I'm thinking of a work around that will not introduce race conditions.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can issue a new `$timeout` after the previous one completes.

Comment: Oh now that I've thought about that makes sense since it will guarantee that  two calls are never out that the same time. I'm going to rewrite that part in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The flush function is intended only for unit testing.  If you want to force your interval task to execute you'll need to stop, execute the task, and then start again.